# Im in the beginning of the Flask tutorial for python, and I dont understand this paragraph

Tags: python, flask

> Usually, it is a good idea to load a configuration from a configurable file. This is what `from_envvar()` can do, replacing the `from_object()` line above:
>
> `app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)`
>
> That way someone can set an environment variable called `FLASKR_SETTINGS` to specify a config file to be loaded which will then override the default values. The silent switch just tells Flask to not complain if no such environment key is set.

I am not too familiar with environment variables. I would like an explanation of the above paragraph in simple terms. My best guess is that when the program reads `FLASKR_SETTING` does that mean that on my own computer I have set up a mapping to this file with that name with something called an environment variable? Ive messed with my environment path before and to be honest I still don't understand it, so I came here looking for a clear answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are a name,value pair that are defined for a particular process running on a computer (windows or UNIX/LINUX etc.). They are not files. You can create your own environment variables and give it any name/value. For example, FLASKR_SETTING is the name of the environment variable who value could be set to a config file. On a UNIX terminal for example, you can do:

```
export FLASKR_SETTING = /somepath/config.txt
```

By doing the above, you have just created an environment variable named FLASKR_SETTING whose value is set to /somepath/config.txt. The reason you use environment variables is because you can tie them to a certain process and use on demand when your process starts. You don't have to worry about saving them in a file. In fact, you can create a launch script for your process/application that can set a variety of environment variables before you starting using the application.

In case of flask, app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True) sets the value of FLASKR_SETTINGS to the value from the env. variable. So it basically translates to:

```
- Find the config file (/somepath/config.txt etc.)
- lets say the contents of config file is:
    SECRET_KEY="whatever"
    DEBUG = True
- Then using the 2 above, it will be translated to:
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "whatever"
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

So this way, you can just update the config file as needed and you will not need to change your code.

Comment: Thanks, this and the other answer helped a lot. I just have a bit of confusion left. You said by creating an environment variable named FLASKR, it creates a "value" set to a config text file. What is this value. Am I supposed to open the config and put in my database config so that when my program does app.config['flaskr'] it will go to the config text file and see my settings and load them?

Comment: actually i made a correction and some edits to explain this better. See my edited answer. The environment variable just points to the config file which has the actual configuration details like DEBUG=True etc.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables are a simple, ad-hoc way of passing information to programs.  On unixy machines, from a command shell, it's as simple as

```
export FLASKR_SETTINGS=/path/to/settings.conf
/path/to/program
```

This is especially useful when installing programs to start up at reboot; the configuration can be easily included in the same setup script that launches the system program.